# Does Alzheimer affect more than day-to-day memory?

Tags: brain, memory

I know that *Alzheimer's* damages a part of the brain called the **hippocampus**, which has a central role in *day-to-day* memory.

But, could it affect also on things in other memory centers, things such as taste and moves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, yes, though short-term memory loss is often an early sign.

"For many, decline in non-memory aspects of cognition, such as word-finding, vision/spatial issues, and impaired reasoning or judgment, may signal the very early stages of Alzheimer’s disease."  from https://www.nia.nih.gov/alzheimers/publication/alzheimers-disease-fact-sheet.  Warning: grim.

Whatever your brain does, Altzheimer's eventually undoes.  For more details:  http://www.alzheimers.net/stages-of-alzheimers-disease/

Comment: "`For more details:www.alzheimers...`". Just in case the link goes dead, could you summarize those details.